# Bash test for command exit status

Tags: bash

I've created a little rsync script to sync my podcasts.  I've configured the script to email me when it's done.  I am attempting to test rsync's exit status to decide which message gets sent.  Here is the block:

```
my_command= rsync --log-file=/home/jake/logs/rsync.log -avzu $local_directory  $remote_directory  
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  
    $mail_expression_success  
else  
    $mail_expression_fail  
fi
```

No matter how the command finishes I get the message contained in the first variable. `$mail_expression_success`.

Comment: Where are you executing the rsync command? It seems like you are just assigning it to a variable, which always succeeds.

Comment: Why do you think the rsync is failing?  The code you have posted here looks fine (but a little odd, since the assignment of the null string to `my_command` is unused).

Comment: Two issues: if `my_command="rsync..."` is intended, then it really is a variable assignment which always succeeds, although `rsync` is never actually called. If the intention is to capture the output of `rsync` with `my_command=$(rsync ...)`, then `rsync` is called, but instead of assigning the output to `my_command`, `rsync` is simply run in an environment where `my_command` is null valued (and ignored by `rsync`). In the latter case, it does seem, as William Pursell points out, that `rsync` is simply succeeding.

Answer (score 2):

It's better just to do something like this:

```
if rsync ....
then
       echo Yay
else
       echo Oh noes
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is this:

```
my_command=$(rsync --log-file=/home/jake/logs/rsync.log -avzu $local_directory  $remote_directory)
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then  
    $mail_expression_success  
else  
    $mail_expression_fail  
fi
```

Comment: It is reasonable to assume that the OP intended to do an assignment like this, but the question as posted works just fine and makes the same assignment to `$?` as does this solution, so something else is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a space after `=`.  If you put the space, your value is not properly assigned.  You will be better off not assigning the output to `f` and just checking for the `$?`.